# Using the WebAudio API, is polling the only way to observe changes to the value of an AudioParam?

Tags: javascript, web-audio-api, observers

Am I correct in thinking that we are reduced to polling AudioParams to observe changes to their value?

An AudioParam is created as a property of an AudioNode, eg:

```
var gainNode = audioContext.createGain();
var param = gainNode.gain;
```

The param is an object with a bunch of methods and properties for controlling the gain of the node. To observe changes, we need to observe the param's 'value' property.

The problem is Object.observe fails silently:

```
Object.observe(param, function(changes){
    console.log(changes);
});
```

Here the callback is never called.

You can also reconfigure the 'value' property as a getter/setter and call the observing code whenever value is set – but that also fails silently. The property is configurable, and you can set a value on it, but the audio node does not appear to use the getter to get the value, so it doesn't use the value we set. I think it should be non-configurable for this reason.

I can understand why these methods would be undesirable – AudioParam values can get updated at the sample rate, so these observers could potentially be called thousands of times per second.

So the question is, are we reduced to polling to observe changes to the value of an AudioParam object (albeit on requestAnimationFrame, but still, polling), or is there a better way?

(I asked this question a few days ago on the public-audio mailing list: http://lists.w3.org/Archives/Public/public-audio/2014JulSep/0054.html. No replies so far.)

Comment: I deleted my answer since it was incorrect. Not sure if my interpretation is right, but it seems the feature only operates on raw   ECMAScript objects - http://wiki.ecmascript.org/doku.php?id=harmony:observe

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We are not sure on how to do that, as this has serious performances implications. In the meantime, I suggest that you just reimplement an AudioParam wrapper that can give you value on the main thread.

Comment: I don't mean to be rude, but who's 'we'? And I'm not sure I understand your comment about making a wrapper. If I make a wrapper, the wrapper still has to listen to changes on the param somehow. The point is to catch changes that are not made by me – changes that are made by the automation methods, for example.

Comment: We are implementors and editors of the Web Audio API (I work on the Web Audio API at Mozilla, and edit the spec at the W3C). My suggestion was exactly to wrap the automation methods of the AudioParam.

Comment: Oh I see! Yup, I suppose that's an alternative. Thanks for clarifying.